# blender_mmd_tools armatures won't work

Tags: armature, add-on

I know I shouldn't blame blender for this, but it's not like there's a blender_mmd_tools stack exchange. I don't know a better place to ask.

When I upload a pmx model, there doesn't seem to be an armature. At least, I can't see one on the 3D view. It's visible on the outliner. It seems to have all the bones. But when I select it on there, I can't change the 3D view to edit or pose mode.

Has anyone else had this problem? Should I try an older version of blender? An older pmx model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this. Usually what I do is first import the model and once it's on the grid, don't touch it. You'll see a small plain axes in the middle, its basically a plus. Delete that and then go to the armature in the upper right hand corner and click the eye to view it.

Comment: I see. The armature is set to invisible. I just need to click the eye to make it visible. I missed that. It looks like the empties are useful for letting you do things like move the whole model, move the whole model but have the hair flow, etc.